# Can I speed up Python multiprocessing further with Pools?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Right now, I have 2 processes. Process 1 (proc_1) receives input, processes it and sends to Process 2 (proc_2) via a pipe. Process 2 does the same thing but ends after processing and printing.

This is an oversimplified version of my issue, but is there any way to utilize multiprocessing.Pool (or other methods) to further speed up each process by using more CPU cores?

The actual processing will be extracting packet data from tshark output. Currently, processing 1,000,000 packets sent in 1 minute takes about 7 minutes to fully process using 3 (Python) processes.

My Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Pool
import time

def proc_1(pipe, pipe2):
    p_output, p_input = pipe
    p_output2, p_input2 = pipe2
    p_input.close()
    p_output2.close()
    
    while True:
        msg = '\n' + p_output.recv() + ' Proc 1'
        time.sleep(1)
        print(msg)
        p_input2.send(msg)
        if 'DONE' in msg:
            break
        
def proc_2(pipe2):
    p_output2, p_input2 = pipe2
    p_input2.close()
    while True:
        msg = p_output2.recv()
        msg += ' Proc 2'
        time.sleep(1)
        print(msg)
        if 'DONE' in msg:
            break

def writer(count, p_input):
    for ii in range(0, count):
        p_input.send(str(ii))             # Write 'count' numbers into the input pipe
    p_input.send('DONE')

if __name__=='__main__':
    p_output, p_input = Pipe()  # writer() writes to p_input from _this_ process
    p_output2, p_input2 = Pipe()  # writer() writes to p_input from _this_ process
    reader_p = Process(target=proc_1, args=((p_output, p_input), (p_output2, p_input2)))
    reader_p2 = Process(target=proc_2, args=((p_output2, p_input2),))
    reader_p.start()     # Launch the reader process
    reader_p2.start()     # Launch the reader process
    writer(3, p_input) # Send stuff to p_input
    reader_p.join()
    reader_p2.join()
```

I have tried:

```
Pool(4, proc_1, (p_output, p_input, p_output2, p_input2))
```

And changing proc_1 to accept 4 arguments. However, proc_1 doesn't print anything after sending data to p_input.

Comment: The structure here is fine, but we cannot comment on whether additional cores will help without knowing what processing you are actually doing.  If each process can keep busy while the next process is also keeping busy, then it can work.

Comment: Let's say I dont need the output to be in order, is it not possible to scrap multiprocessing,Process in favor of Pools, use a pool for each previous process, and assign multiple cores to each pool?

Comment: @TimRoberts added some info on the actual processing. Thanks.

Comment: You don't do any "assigning" to cores.  The operating system assigns whatever processes are ready to run, to whatever cores are available.  You can certainly use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to pass stuff from one process to the next, or even a TCP socket.